# Issue while using CometD in LWC to subscribe for platform event from another ORG

Tags: apex, platform-event, cometd

I am trying to subscribe to Platform event using the LWC component.

Platform Event is being published from a different Salesforce ORG and I need to subscribe it  in a different Salesforce ORG.

I have used CometD 3.1.1 library and getting below errors. I have added the URL in Remote Site Setting, Trusted URLs as well. Does any one have any idea on how to fix this error?

**Error Screenshot**
[image: Getting the below errors.]

**LWC Component Code**

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc'; 
import { loadStyle, loadScript } from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";
import cometd from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/CometD3";
import getSessionId from '@salesforce/apex/TestPlatformeventApex.getSessionId';
export default class DemoPlatformEvents extends LightningElement {
  isLoaded=false;
  libInitialized=false;

@wire(getSessionId)
wiredSessionId({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
        //console.log(data);
        this.sessionId = data;
        this.error = undefined;
        loadScript(this, cometd)
        .then(() => {
                                    //console.log('######In SessionmessageRecords:'+this.messageRecords);
                this.initializecometd()
        });
    } else if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            this.error = error;
            this.sessionId = undefined;
        }
}

initializecometd() {
    if (this.libInitialized) {
        return;
    }
    this.libInitialized = true;
    //inintializing cometD object/class
    var cometdlib = new window.org.cometd.CometD();
    //Calling configure method of cometD class, to setup authentication which will be used in handshaking
    const externalAppAccessToken = 'Secret_Key';
    cometdlib.configure({
        url: 'https://kion--partial.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/cometd/59.0/',
        requestHeaders: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + externalAppAccessToken , 
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*' },
        appendMessageTypeToURL : false,
        logLevel: 'debug'
    });
    //console.log('#####SessionID:'+this.sessionId);
    cometdlib.websocketEnabled = false;

    cometdlib.handshake(function(status) {
        if(status.successful) {
            // Successfully connected to the server.
            // Now it is possible to subscribe or send messages
            console.log('#####Successfully connected to server');
           
                            let self = this;
                            cometdlib.subscribe('/event/Test_Demo_Platform_Event__e',function(msg) {
                                    console.log("this.Event msg:::"+JSON.stringify(msg));
                                    //self.invokeLWCApexMethod();
                            });
        } else {
            /// Cannot handshake with the server, alert user.
            console.error("#####Error in handshaking:" + JSON.stringify(status));
        }
    });
}
```

}